# Inserting table record without geometry into feature class using Python?

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase

I am working with ArcGIS and Python and trying to append table rows into a feature class.

You cannot use append and you cannot just make a table view of the feature class and then try to append it in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Table Join - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000.htm

Comment: If you actually mean to append featureless (no geometry) records into a feature class... why would you want to? That somewhat defeats the purpose, does it not? Besides, how would the attributes match up? I may be misunderstanding the question, however, in which case, I feel more information is needed.

Comment: @Nathanus One reason would be with the intention of creating the geometry out of the attributes at a later stage.  Another is that null geometries can represent facts about the features: it's the old distinction between zero and nodata, played out on a geometric, rather than a numeric, stage.

Comment: ESRI doesn't allow this through normal methods. However I happen to know that a geocoded file which has unplaced addresses is just such an animal. Also found in an annotation fc. HTH

Comment: @whuber In the latter example, is the shape file really even needed as opposed a simple attribute that describes the presence, or lack of, data? And I do not understand the distinction between zero and nodata. That is to say, I've never studied/encountered the concept to my knowledge. Could you direct me to some information on the topic?

Comment: @Nathanus [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) will give you a start in an RDBMS context ("Null" is one form of nodata).  According to RDBMS rules, every field in a table has to have something stored in it, so if some of your records have valid shapes and others don't, you need a shapefile (or its equivalent) and it has to hold null shapes.  Moreover, what do you do to represent a parcel of land that now is permanently under water, for instance?  Or to represent a parcel that you know exists but you don't yet have info about its shape and location?

Comment: @whuber Ah, you mean Null when you say nodata. I was unfamiliar with the term. I suppose I understand your reasoning, but I think a little discussion would be nice to help me put some nails in the coffin of my curiosity. I will leave you a note in the chat.

Comment: Null geometries are allowed in ArcGIS and can even be created in the user interface.  For instance, creating a new feature in a feature class via the table UI will create a null geometry.  I believe this question is misguided though a join would meet his needs.

Comment: @Craig the UI creates a template of a Null geometry, but it will not allow you to save it. If you find a way to do it through thr UI, it is a bug.

Comment: @Ragi Try what I suggested and you'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: @Craig. I am 100% sure that if you can insert null geometries through some GUI combination - it is a bug. You should not be able to do that. Trust me, I spent several years adding guard code inside the GeoDatabase to account for those cases to avoid crashes. Don't do it.

Comment: Times have changed and these are valid now.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot (or are not supposed to). When I worked at GDB team, we spent time every once in awhile fixing bugs for processes that create Null geometries. The reason there is a "Find Empty geometries tool" is to fix this very thing (since some gp processes can potentially create empty processes).

As mentioned in some of the comments, there are some **Complex FeatureClasses** that have some internals that rely on some geometries columns being NULL, but these are handled through special codepaths - you should not attempt to create this situation within ArcGIS because you will start getting unexpected behavior.

Don't do it :)

Answer (score 2):

To get around the same issue, I created geometries for objects that had them, and default geometries for ones that didn't, added a flag called IsCurrent and set it to 1 and 0, in each case.  You can easily apply a filter to view or update either.